# Slug preview on sonata

Tags: symfony, slug, sonata

i'm studing about sonata, but i don't understand how i can put on sonata admin's page the preview of slug

i'm looking for a text field that onChange event (or similar) update a div with text transformed in slug

example: 
in input text on sonata edit page:
My Title

and in a div show

my-title

is possible?

sluggable in gedmo/doctrine-extensions can be useful?

thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the exact issue you are facing.

Comment: the problem is that i don't know where i must start